# Pyqt GUI with multiple tabs

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer, qtabwidget

I use QT designer and pyqt4 for GUI widgets designing and programming. I designed a tab widget inside which several required widgets are placed. Now I wish to add another tab and in runtime, if I switch between tabs, clone of widgets in tab 1 should be displayed in tab2 and should handle it accordingly. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @eyllanesc code is vast... can i know what info you want regarding the code ?

Comment: You could place a minimum code, replicable and reproducible where you show what you have tried. Also represent what you want to do.

Comment: Since you didn't give much code or specified a little bit more what you really need I gave a quickly example right bellow, hope it helps you ")

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's exactly what you need, but I think you can get some ideas from the following code where I have only three "guys".

1. MyWidget -> Where you put the content of the tab, you can add whatever you want in there.
2. WidgetTab -> The cotent that contains everything, it contains your "MyWidget" and your tabs.
3. TabBarPlus -> This one is the tab itself, I put a plus button where you can add tabs in runtime clicking on a small "+" button. If you double click on the tab you can rename it.

**Note:** As I said it's only a simple way I choose to do and I hope you can infer what you need from this example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    default_name = "New"

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("""
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    background:rgb(37,43,52,220);
                """)
        self.name = self.default_name




class TabBarPlus(QTabBar):
    """Tab bar that has a plus button floating to the right of the tabs."""

    plusClicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TabBarPlus, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet(
        """
            QTabBar::tab {
                width: 80px;

            }

           QTabBar::tab:selected {
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-size: 18px;
                font: italic;
                color: rgb(0,0,0,255);

                background: rgb(234,234,234,255);
                border-top-left-radius: 8px;
                border-top-right-radius: 8px;

                border:1px;
                border-color: rgb(197,197,199,255);
                border-top-style: solid;
                border-right-style: solid;
                border-left-style: solid;
                padding: 10px 50px 10px 24px;

           }

           QTabBar::tab:!selected{
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-size: 18px;
                font: italic;
                color: rgb(255,255,255,255);
                background: rgb(175,175,175,255);
                border-top-left-radius: 8px;
                border-top-right-radius: 8px;

               border:1px;
                border-color: rgb(197,197,199,255);
                border-top-style: solid;
                border-right-style: solid;
                border-bottom-style: ;
                border-left-style: solid;
                padding: 10px 50px 10px 24px;
            }

        """)
        # Plus Button
        self.plusButton = QPushButton("+")
        self.plusButton.setParent(self)
        self.plusButton.setMaximumSize(20, 20) # Small Fixed size
        self.plusButton.setMinimumSize(20, 20) # Small Fixed size
        self.plusButton.clicked.connect(self.plusClicked.emit)
        self.movePlusButton() # Move to the correct location
    # end Constructor

    def sizeHint(self):
        """Return the size of the TabBar with increased width for the plus button."""
        sizeHint = QTabBar.sizeHint(self)
        width = sizeHint.width()
        height = sizeHint.height()
        return QSize(width+25, height)
    # end tabSizeHint

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        """Resize the widget and make sure the plus button is in the correct location."""
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        self.movePlusButton()
    # end resizeEvent

    def tabLayoutChange(self):
        """This virtual handler is called whenever the tab layout changes.
        If anything changes make sure the plus button is in the correct location.
        """
        super().tabLayoutChange()

        self.movePlusButton()
    # end tabLayoutChange

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() != Qt.LeftButton:
            super(TabBarPlus, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)

        idx = self.currentIndex()
        ok = True
        self.input_dialog = QInputDialog()
        print(type(self.input_dialog.textEchoMode()))

        newName, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Mudar nome',
                                        'Novo nome:')

        if ok:
            self.setTabText(idx, newName)

    def open_kb(self):
        print("open keyboard")



    def movePlusButton(self):
        """Move the plus button to the correct location."""
        # Find the width of all of the tabs
        size = 0
        for i in range(self.count()):
            size += self.tabRect(i).width()

        # Set the plus button location in a visible area
        h = self.geometry().top()
        w = self.width()
        if size > w: # Show just to the left of the scroll buttons
            self.plusButton.move(w-54, h)
        else:
            self.plusButton.move(size, h)

    # end movePlusButton
# end class MyClass

class WidgetTab(QTabWidget):

    layout = None
    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetTab, self).__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            border-radius: 4px;
            background:rgb(37,43,52,220);
        """)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setMinimumSize(800,400)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        # Tab Bar
        self.tab = TabBarPlus(self)
        self.setTabBar(self.tab)

        # Properties
        # self.setMovable(True)
        # Signals
        self.tab.plusClicked.connect(self.add_tab)
        self.tab.tabMoved.connect(self.tab.movePlusButton)
        self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)

        self.add_tab()




    def add_tab(self):
        if self.count() >0:
            self.setTabsClosable(True)
        else:
            self.setTabsClosable(False)



        my_widget = MyWidget()


        self.addTab(my_widget,my_widget.name)

    def removeTab(self, p_int):
        if self.count() > 1:
            self.setTabsClosable(True)
        else:
            self.setTabsClosable(False)

        try:
            self.chart.removeSeries(self.series[p_int])
            self.tables.remove(self.tables[p_int])
            self.models.remove(self.models[p_int])
            self.series.remove(self.series[p_int])
        except:
            pass

        super(WidgetTab, self).removeTab(p_int)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def update_axes(self):

        for s in self.series:
            self.chart.removeSeries(s)
            self.chart.addSeries(s)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wt = WidgetTab()
    wt.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great answer !!